# Detecting Player by RayCasting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem in raycasting where my ray cannot detect the player even if I did layermask and went to draw ray and all other stuff. But it is still not working.

[image]

Here is my code:

```cs
RaycastHit2D raycastHit2D = Physics2D.Raycast(enemyEyes.transform.position, new Vector2(directionOfRay, 0), LayerMask.GetMask("Player"));

    if(raycastHit2D.collider != null )
    {
        if (raycastHit2D.collider.gameObject.tag=="Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit Hit");
        }
    }
  
    Debug.DrawRay(enemyEyes.transform.position,new Vector3(directionOfRay , 0,0)  , Color.red);
```

The problem is HIT HIT is not displaying in the console.

Raycasting Problem where my ray is unable to detect my player.

Answer (score 0):

Player Must Have Collider assigned in it.
Try This:

```
    RaycastHit2D hitObstacle = Physics2D.Raycast (obstacleRayObject.transform.position, Vector2.right, obstacleRayDistance, layerMask);

    if (hitObstacle.collider != null) {

        Debug.DrawRay (obstacleRayObject.transform.position, Vector2.right * hitObstacle.distance * new Vector2 (characterDirection, 0f), Color.red);
        Debug.Log ("Object Detected");
    } else {
        Debug.DrawRay (obstacleRayObject.transform.position, Vector2.right * obstacleRayDistance * new Vector2 (characterDirection, 0f), Color.green);

    }
```

Comment: Thank You I got it .I beleive Unity should resolve this confusion